# Java BigDecimal divide and get digit to N places

Tags: java, decimal, bigdecimal

I am trying to write a program that has a step in it where I would like to divide two numbers and get a decimal number to 60 places.

For instance, I would like to divide 1 by 17 and get 0.016393442622950819672131147540983606557377049180327868852459 without losing any precision.

I am trying to store the number in a `BigDecimal` but I am having trouble finding a good way to accomplish this without losing the precision after the 16th digit or so

Comment: Add some code please.

Comment: BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(1);
      BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(17);
      
      System.out.println(a.divide(b, 60, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));